# Why ls -Q give output as "Z\\1" if the file name is 'Z\1'?

Tags: linux, ls

```
$ touch "z\1"
$ ls -Q
"z\\1"
```

Why "ls -Q" give output as `"z\\1"` if the file name is '`z\1`'?

The output is coming with double slash in between 'z' and '1'.

Comment: "give output as "Z\1" if the file name is 'Z\1'" - well, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: the double slash inside is coming as a single slash. The output is coming with double slash in between 'z' and '1'.

Comment: That's the joke. But seriously, read up on backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Q`-Switch (also `--quote-names`) will quote the names. How this quoting is done is defined by the `--quoting-style`-Switch.

Snippet from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

> --quoting-style=WORD
>                 use quoting style WORD for entry names: literal, locale,
>                 shell, shell-always, c, escape

This will lead to the following result:

- `ls --quoting-style=literal "z\1"` => `z\1`
- `ls --quoting-style=locale "z\1"` => `‘z\\1’`
- `ls --quoting-style=shell "z\1"` => `'z\1'`
- `ls --quoting-style=shell-always "z\1"` => `'z\1'`
- `ls --quoting-style=c "z\1"` => `"z\\1"`
- `ls --quoting-style=escape "z\1"` => `z\\1`

I can't tell you what the default is. But it have to be one of these `locale, c, escape`

Comment: -Q should only enclose with quote. ls -b is also giving the same kind of output.

Comment: That is correct. My question is it should only enclose entry names in double quotes why giving an extra backslash with it?

Comment: @sameerpradhan In fact, -Q is equivalent to `--quoting-style=c`, -N is equivalent to literal, -b is equivalent to escape. I fixed the typos in the answer but I'm not sure how best to incorporate this explanation in the answer. See http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-the-file-names.html